# Doctrine duplicating query results?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following code

```
$this->em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');


$qb = $this->em->getRepository('CoreBundle:ServiceProvider')->createQueryBuilder('c');
$qb->select('count(venue.id) as vencount');
$qb->from('CoreBundle:ServiceProvider','venue');

$count = $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult()['vencount'];
```

which is write its returning a number of venues but the problem is that this number is mistaken because in the ServiceProvider table i have only 5 records but this query is returning 25. I tried to add a new record so they are 6 and yes the result was 36.

So I added group by the id and it fixed the issue anyone can tell me why is this happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when you create a query from a repository Doctrine assumes its a select and inject the select and from clausule's for you.

This is the sql you get from using the getRepository method:

```
SELECT count(i0_.id) AS sclr_0 FROM Entity i1_, Entity i0_
```

(Note that the entity is twice in the FROM).

Using just:

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('count(venue.id) as vencount');
$qb->from('CoreBundle:ServiceProvider','venue');
```

You get:

```
SELECT count(i0_.id) AS sclr_0 FROM Entity i0_
```

Which is probably what you are looking for.

Another alternative is to get it from the repository but clear the sql parts with:

```
$qb = $this->em->getRepository('CoreBundle:ServiceProvider')->createQueryBuilder('c')->resetDQLParts();
```

But this way you lost the very purpose of using the repository in the first place.